# How can I change the order of elements in a TOC without changing the layout?

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I'm pretty solid on TOC's in InDesign CC, but this structure has me scratching my head! Maybe the answer is obvious, and I did see a post on linking text boxes backwards, but that is not working for me. I've tried several TOC Style option settings and I still can't get this right.

Is there a way to “trick” the order so that the TOC isn't generated sequentially by elements on the page? I hope this image will help you understand what I'm trying to do.

I could do a work-around and generate the TOC first, then go back chapter-by-chapter and move the Chapter Title below the text box information. Is that the only way?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a trick, not so clean but works.

### Normal TOC

[image]

### Fixed TOC

Start the chapter title in a small text frame on top of the info frame and link it with the real text frame where the chapter title must be:

[image]

Comment: I get it! Thank you, Daniellillo. As you said, not too clean but it is a trick that will work. At least I know I wasn't missing something to begin with :-).