# How can I ensure InDesign's TOC is in the correct order?

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

So I have created a TOC in indesign, and for some reason everything has moved up by one page; ie. The category header sits below the first category for that section. It is bending my brain and I cannot see where the error is?

[image: TOC needing to be fixed]

[image: TOC with characters on]

[image: TOC Style]

[image: What the final table needs to look like]

Additional pages; 
Page 4 Blue Subheader has paragraph style that aligns with TOC
and all subsequent pages of the same category have a duplicate paragraph style for the Blue Subheader NOT assigned to TOC in order for them to be skipped. Up until the next main category blue header.

[image: Updated TOC]

[image: Page 4]

[image: Page 5]

[image: Page 8]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the order of elements in a TOC without changing the layout?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119831/how-can-i-change-the-order-of-elements-in-a-toc-without-changing-the-layout)

Comment: Please edit your post and add screenshots : normal view + hidden characters on

Comment: @Vinny That is done now can you help?Is it something to do with my pagination and numbering?

Comment: @sarahdawn Thanks, can you add a sample of a page like 5, 9 or 14 ?

Comment: @Vinny Thankkkk you!!!! I need to get this off to client asap so am so so so greatful for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I looked at the screenshots and can tell you what happens.
In case of separate text frames, TOC will get the one on the left first.
So you have several options : thread your frames, make a unique frame and use left indentation in order to position your title 1 or extend your title 2 frame to the left and again, use left indent.
If I had to do it, i would go for unique text frame. Multiplying frames usually multiply issues :-)